# Does Jquery UI Accordion requires a div after each h tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Here is my original code:

```
 <div id="accordion">
    <h1>Header #1</h1>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">List item #1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h1>Header #2</h1>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">List item #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List item #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List item #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List item #4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to remove the inner `div` tags, and the code worked just fine. The only difference is that when I surround the `ul` tags with `div` tags, it creates some margin around them.

Every documentation or tutorial I came across about Jquery UI Accordion, uses `div` tags after the `h` tags, but since it is working also without them, I ask my self if they are required.

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: It might be used to get in with proper structure of `html` which might or might not effect the functionality. So when you remove any elements you might need to check all the functionalities to see that it hasn't broken anywhere.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just scanned the jQuery UI github source, the accordion seem to work on the class `ui-accordion-content` - so it should be OK - as long as you use a block element (p / div / ul etc).

`https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/search?utf8=✓&q=ui-accordion-content`

Comment: So I could use pretty much every element if it has `display: block` on it?

Comment: Theoretically, it should be possible - but due to the associated browser styles, it is recommended to use a neutral container - like div. I tried with p tag, and it still works. Any reason why you cannot go for a div?

Comment: Because the content is a list, and it has a well established container - `ul`, so why surround it by another one?